# Newton's Method Glitch

Tags: equation-solving

I wonder if you can help me with my program - it involves using Newton's Method but my main issue is getting a defined function to return a given value.

Essentially, I want to get my function `findRoot` to return the value of the root or `Null` if it doesn't find one. Here is the code for this function:

```
findRoot[x0_] := Module[{Root},
(*Initialise dummy variable and counter index thing *)
dumx = x0;
l = 0;

While[l < 100,
Root = Iter[dumx];
If[Norm[dumx - Root] < TOL, Break[], dumx = Root]

 (*If true, break the while loop and return root, if false let dumx=Root*)
 ; l++]


If[l == 100, Null, Root]
];
```

`Iter[]` is just another function that performs iterations of Newton's method, I made it separate to allow ease of debugging!

Essentially, if I plug

> ```
> {-0.3,-0.3,-0.3,-0.3}
> ```

into this algorithm, (With certain global variables set in ways where I already know what roots should come out of this function) I get

> ```
> {-0.2Null,-0.2Null,-0.2Null,-0.2Null}
> ```

and I have no idea where the null is coming from. The result should read `{-0.2,-0.2,-0.2,-0.2}`. I suspect the semi-colon on line 7 is responsible for this `Null`, but removing it causes greater issues.

Comment: You should try to provide a minimal example where everything is defined. As it stands now, your question is not easy to interpret.

Comment: Maybe you are missing a ; at the penultimate "if" condition i.e. after l++]

Comment: @dionys Sorry, thank you for the advice. I should have lurked more before posting but I am in a slight rush to move on from this glitch.

Comment: A more idiomatic way of doing what you're doing is `FixedPoint[{#[[1]] + 1, iter[#[[2]]]} &, {0, x0}, 100, 
 SameTest -> (Abs[#1[[2]] - #2[[2]]] < tol &)] /. {{100,x_} :> Null, {a_, b_} :> b }`, by the way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an attempt at a clean example using a stand-in definition for `Iter`. Note: it's generally better to avoid creating symbols that start with a capital letter or shadow built-in functions, so I've changed a couple variable names in obvious ways:

```
findRoot[x0_] := Module[{myRoot, iter, tol, result},
  iter[x_] = RandomReal[];
  dumx = x0;
  tol = 1;
  l = 0;
  While[l < 100,
        myRoot = iter[dumx];
        If[Norm[dumx - myRoot] < tol, Break[], dumx = myRoot]; l++];
        result = If[l == 100, Null, myRoot]]

findRoot[10]
(*0.371588*)
```

[Newton's method](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UnconstrainedOptimizationNewtonsMethodRoot.html) is the default approach implemented in the built-in function [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html), so the following is analogous to your code above, operating on the function `Sin[x - 10] - x + 10`:

```
Module[{f},
  f[x_] = Sin[x - 10] - x + 10;
  FindRoot[f[x], {x, 0}, Method -> "Newton", AccuracyGoal -> 1, PrecisionGoal -> 1]]
```

Comment: So you are allowed as many semi-colons as you wish in the body of the while loop? It wasn't entirely clear from when I was reading the online documentation.

Comment: @MathewVaughan It's a little more complicated than that, you should have a look at the answer here: [Understand that semicolon (;) is not a delimiter](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18617/193).

Comment: This helped me, turns out it was a syntax issue whilst using 'While'. Also, thanks for your advice!