# Code for Newton's Method

Tags: equation-solving, programming

I'm trying to write a program for finding the root of f(x)=e^x+sin(x)-4 by Newton's Method but I'm instructed to not use the built in function and write the code from scratch.  I'm pretty new to this and this is what I've come up with so far.  I'm curious about what I need to fix to make it better/work.

```
f[x_]:= Exp[x]+Sin[x]-4 (* This is my starting function *)
g[x_]:= x-(f[x]/f'[x])  (* Formula for Newton's Method *)
count=0;
maxiterations=100; (* Max times function will run *)
TOL=10^(-8); (* Tolerance for stopping condition *)
xprevious=1.0; (* This is my initial guess *)

While[Abs[xcurrent-xprevious] >= TOL && count <= maxiterations,
 {count++, xcurrent=g[xcurrent]}]

(* While my current and previous guess are above my tolerance and I haven't gone over 
my max iterations program will continue to run, adding one to the count each time and
putting xcurrent into the Newton's Method Equation *)
```

Obviously I am having some troubles with this code.  What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is read a few tutorials and at least get familiar with the basic syntax. Go to the documentation centre, click Common How-Tos at the bottom and read the first few.  "`f(x_)`" is not a function in Mathematica.

Comment: functions use square brackets. Euler's e is written with a capital E. Built-in keywords always start with a capital (sin -> Sin)

Comment: Sorry I do know that I just typed it in wrong.

Comment: Related: [(59877)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59877), [(93957)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/93957)

Answer (score 2):

For a beginner one hint:

```
f[x_] = Exp[x] + Sin[x] - 4 // N;
NestList[(# - f[#]/f'[#]) &, 1, 5]
{1, 1.1351, 1.12999, 1.12998, 1.12998, 1.12998}
```

Please read the documentation

Comment: Or `NestWhileList[(# - f[#]/f'[#]) &, 1, TOL < Abs[#1 - #2] &, 2]`

Comment: @ march I said "one hint":)

Comment: Or just `FixedPointList[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, 1.]` or `FixedPoint[# - f[#]/f'[#] &, 1.]`

Comment: Oh I see, I guess I gave away the answer you were hinting at. :) Oh, and @BobHanlon is piling on with more hints!

Comment: @march life's a bitch!

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot.  Now what if I want the answer to be within 8 decimal places? I know the N gives a numerical value and I tried N[f[x],8] at the end but the code never stopped evaluating.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is reasonable to try to produce correct and robust code that will apply Newton's algorithm for finding a zero of a differentiable function of one real variable while maintaining the OP's procedural style.

For robustness, a clear distinction will be made between arguments and localized ancillary variables. The arguments will be

- ***f***, the function for which a zero is sought
- ***guess***, the initial guess for the location of the root
- ***maxiter***, the maximum number of iteration to performed before giving up
- ***tolerance***, the distance between two iterates of the root that is considered good enough to terminate the solver. This will an optional argument with the default of `1.*^-8` as specified by the OP.

The solver uses Newton's formula to derive a pure function iterator from the function passed to it. That *Mathematica* can do this symbolically is a great advantage.

The solver will return `$Failed` if fails to converge after `maxiter` iterations.

```
solver[f : (_Function | _Symbol),
     guess_?NumericQ,
     maxiter_Integer /; maxiter > 0,
     tolerance : _?NumericQ : 1.*^-8] /; .1 > tolerance > 0. :=
   Module[{iter, count, xprevious, xcurrent},
     iter = (# - f[#]/f'[#] &);
     count = 0;
     xcurrent = guess;
     xprevious = guess + 2.;
     While[Abs[xcurrent - xprevious] >= tolerance && count <= maxiter,
       xcurrent = iter[xprevious = xcurrent];
       count++];
     If[count <= maxiter, xcurrent, $Failed]]
```

Let's see if the solver can solve the OP's example problem, i.e., finding a root near `1.` for the function

```
f[x_] := Exp[x] + Sin[x] - 4

 With[{x = solver[f, 1., 5]}, {x, f[x]}]
```

> ```
> {1.12998, 0.}
> ```

Here it finds $\sqrt{2}$

```
Module[{f = #^2 - 2. &, x}, x = solver[f, 1., 6, 1.*^-15]; {x, f[x]}]
```

> ```
> {1.41421, -4.44089*10^-16}
> ```